# Wifi network not found

Tags: android, windows-10, wifi, huawei-mobile-services

I have usb wifi dongle in my PC Windows 10. the device is this: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00ECXY0GQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I have an wifi modem with 4G sim. The device is: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0866BKZHP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The problem is, my pc many times fails to find the Huawei modem wifi, says no network found. While that pc can connect to any nearby smartphone hotspot but not the Huawei modem. At the same time all the smartphones can find and connect with the Huawei modem. Only the pc fails to find it. Restarting the Huawei device and the PC sometimes resolves the problem but sometimes not. Please suggest something to solve it. I have searched a lot in last 2 months but found no solution.